# How to draw 3D user location model among 3D buildings on MapBox iOs SDK

Tags: mapbox-ios

I'm using Mapbox 10.2.0 sdk for iOs.

I've imported 3d puck (user location marker) on a map in my iOs application. I also have a 3d buildings layer extruded above the ground. The problem is that 3d user marker and buildings are on different layers, thus user location marker is getting drawn above the buildings or vice versa. I want 3d puck to exist on the same layer as buildings and be rendered among those.

Is that even possible?

From the code I see that I can't configure which layer the puck is on, and it looks like that whole layer is getting rotated to reflect the direction user facing.

UPD: I realised i describe the problem in the wrong way.

User location marker model is layer of type `ModelLayer` and buildings are `FillExtrusion layers`, I don't see any tool that would allow me to merge those. Are there any?

UPD: Ok, so there are renderers. And they are different for all layers. So that means that different renderers are unaware of one another and my data should all be on single layer. But that means that I need to create third layer of type `custom` that copies 3d models, and it does not handle the problem that usel location marker need to rotate (it's 3d model).

So back to the initial question. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, but all classes responsible for that are internal. You should create a feature request here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-ios/issues/new?labels=feature%20%3Agreen_apple%3A&template=feature.md

What you need is expose Puck3d configuration add ModelLayerStyle property.